# search using regex functionality in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am searching for a keyword using SQL server and Regex Functionality.

we have a data like leaky gas, leaked gas, and leaking gas.

```
SELECT [Text field]
FROM [Global database] 
text field is like '%leak[a-z]{1,3} gas%'
```

Comment: Could this help you ?

Select [Text field] from [Global database] text field is like '%leak%gas%'

Comment: I don't want text search where like "the leak is not from gas."

Comment: WHERE Clause is missing..

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server does not support regular expressions (unless you add your own UDF).  It does however extend the `LIKE` functionality for some basic wildcards.

You can do what you want as:

```
where field like '%leak[a-z] gas%' or
      field like '%leak[a-z][a-z] gas%' or
      field like '%leak[a-z][a-z][a-z] gas%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regex CLR that can be used in SQL.

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/